# Adding firebase cloud messaging to Flutter project with "firebase init" CLI

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to add Firebase Cloud messaging to an existing Flutter project that never used Firebase before.
According to the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en a run `firebase init`.

This asks me

```
Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices:
  - database
  - emulators
  - firestore
  - functions
  - hosting
  - hosting:github
  - remoteconfig
  - storage
```

I do not need any of this. I only want to generate the `firebase.json` with the CLI which is done by `firebase init` as the docs say. However, if I don't select any of the given options, I get an error: `Error: Must select at least one feature. Use SPACEBAR to select features, or specify a feature by running firebase init [feature_name]`

How is it possible to initialize a Firebase project with the CLI that only uses FCM?

Answer (score 0):

For setting up FCM you don't need to create backend project.You can use below links

For Android:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

For iOS:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: Are you really sure? Your iOS link contains this statement:
`If you haven't already, add Firebase to your Apple project. -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup`.

Isn't this step simplified by the Firebase CLI command `firebase init` or is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Yes this can be done using firebase console. Create a Firebase project on firebase console and Register your app with Firebase. In this scenario you dont have to create project using firebase cli.

Comment: What I do not understand is this: Why do I need to connect my iOS App with my firebase project in order to use FCM? I mean as you said I do not need to this for Android.

Comment: And even for Android it does not work: ` Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.` So I think I need to add the app to my Firebase project. But the CLI that will does it for does not work for cloud messaging only as described in the question.